# Spawning a process return unidentified error and list of option?

Tags: javascript, node.js, imagemagick-convert, pdftotext

I am trying to spawn pdftotext to extract text from pdf but it returns information of available option.

This is the code i used:

```
 var s = spawn('pdftotext',['-upw 12345678','epdf.pdf','out.txt']) 
 console.log(s.stdout)
```

Same happening with Imagemagick whenever i try to join to images with gap between them it returns unrecognized option error :

```
 sar s =spawn('convert',['-background color white','-splice 8X0+0+0','+append' outimage]);

console.log(s.stdout);
```

It returns ` unrecognized option -background color' if i remove background color then it return error for splice how to spawn procesa correctly ?

pdftotext version is 0.62 and convert 6.9.-4

I am on Ubuntu LTS. And node js is version 10.18.1

Comment: Try to split each argument as separate item in array. Like so `spawn('convert', ['-background', 'color', 'white'])` and so on for each argument. So the idea here is that you must not have whitespaces, instead, they should go as separate items. Try it, does it resolve your issue?

Comment: @EugeneObrezkov Thank you very much for your help and support.

Comment: Did it help you? If so, I'll post it as an answer with explanation.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `spawn` in Node.js, you need to separate a list of arguments by whitespace, e.g.:

```
spawn(
  'convert',
  [
    '-background',
    'color',
    'white',
    '-splice',
    '8X0+0+0',
    '+append',
    'out-image.png'
  ]
);
```

So, arguments list **MUST NOT** contain whitespaces, like:

```
spawn('convert', ['-background color white']); // doesn't work
```

Comment: I was too quick to accept. This worked for pdftotext but not for Imagemagicks convert.

Comment: Are you sure that imagemagick has the option you tried to use? Also, `spawn` returns a child process where `stdout` is a stream object, not the data itself. Try to switch to `exec` - https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

Comment: The options are correct as they are working properly if executed from command processor